# 'New Names...' is printing too slowly and is slowing down R Shiny application

Tags: r, tibble

I have an application that prints a lot of 'New names' messages. That was not an issue until recently. Now these chunks are taking longer to print(seems like ~ 1 second lag between each set of messages) and the output in console looks 'prettier' than before- with those blue dots in beginning.

I'm wondering which package I might've erroneously upgraded that landed me in this situation and if I can go back to an older version where these messages printed quickly.

[image]

Really appreciate any help on this. Thank you

Comment: I've always found that message to be frustrating though insightful: if I don't know it's happening, it's good to know that my assumptions are not all true. Having said that, (1) avoid it by ensuring your data has no duplicate column names (especially within dplyr pipes); and (2) if you really want to silence them and avoid the validity of the message, wrap the operation in `suppressMessages`.

Comment: FYI, removing the [tag:shiny] tag as this is almost certainly a `tibble` or `dplyr` issue, nothing to do with `shiny`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Agreed- it surely seems like a dplyr or tibble issue. I actually have a lot of nested lapply chains... Is it possible to apply suppressMessages at app level in global.R so it silences everything?

Comment: Possible? Maybe. Irresponsible, chaotic, likely to result in unforeseen problems and app instability? Very likely. Global meltdown? Probably not. It is likely to interface with the `sink` actions of most reactive blocks in shiny, so even if it were easy, it may not be stable or sustainable. If you want to do it for large blocks of code, keep it to code within a single reactive block, never outside of that. Even then, I suggest you be careful that you don't over-muffle the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output is usual from the `readr` and `readxl` packages (both part of the tidyverse, so related to `dplyr`, but not part of that specific package).

The reason for those messages is that the function is trying set column names from the file and finding some blank "cells" where a name would be expected.  The best solutions are to makes sure that you are reading the correct row for column names, or not set the names from the file.  Or fix the source data files to make sure that all the columns have usable names.